# how change position of a div to bottom?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I used a `magnify zoom in` from this [link](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo_show/252).

I want to change position of a div that shows zoomed image , I want it showed in bottom of small image , because I used responsive design with bootstrap and `overflow-x:hidden`in body, and when I shrink the browser , small imaged cut :/ . can anyone help me ? and sorry for my very bad English

css:

```
div.jqZoomTitle
{
z-index:5000;
text-align:center;
font-size:11px;
font-family:Tahoma;
height:16px;
padding-top:2px;
position:absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
color: #FFF;
background: #999;

}

 .jqZoomPup
  {
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #FFF;
    -moz-opacity:0.6;
    opacity: 0.6;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 60);
    z-index:10;
    border-color:#c4c4c4;
    border-style: solid;
    cursor:crosshair;
   }

   .jqZoomPup img
   {
    border: 0px;
    }

.preload{
-moz-opacity:0.8;
opacity: 0.8;
filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
color: #333;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Tahoma;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
background-color: white;
padding: 8px;
text-align:center;
background-image: url(~/Images/zoomloader.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 43px 30px;
width:90px;
* width:100px;
height:43px;
*height:55px;
z-index:10;
position:absolute;
top:3px;
left:3px;

 }

  .jqZoomWindow
{
border: 1px solid #999;
background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Html :

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>JQzoom Demo</title>
 <script src="../js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../js/jqzoom.pack.1.0.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jqzoom.css" type="text/css">
 <style type"text/css">
  div.notes{
    font-size:12px;
        }
   div.notes a{
   color:#990000;
     }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function() {
           $(".jqzoom").jqzoom();
           });
         </script>
       </head>

   <body>
    <div id="content" style="margin-top:100px;margin-left:100px;">
 <a href="kawasakigreen.jpg" class="jqzoom" style="" title="kawasaki"> 
    <img src="kawasakigreen_small.jpg"  title="kawasakigreen" style="border: 1px solid #666;">
   </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

jqZoom has attributes to position the div.

position    String

Default : right - The popup window position.Admitted values:'right' ,'left' ,'top' ,'bottom'

For reference 
http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jqzoom

Comment: thank you , this link helped me to understand the codes

Comment: this article said add option `bottom` , and I add it but didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

this is because it has position is absolute. so to achieve responsive layout, which is when device is in smaller width i.e.

```
@media(max-width: 768px){.jqZoomWindow{position:relative !important;}}
```

make it's position relative.

that's all folks.

Comment: Thank you , I added your codes and it works , but I have a footer in bottom of page and zoomed image showed under the footer , I'm not well in css , can you help me How fix it ? Thanks

Comment: put the css of footer in comment

Comment: oright use this  `@media(max-width: 768px){footer.footer{position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%}}`

Comment: thank you again , I changed it to your new code but it's not true :/ my output showed in this image http://s3.picofile.com/file/8226062176/22.jpg